Jumping POinter Ubuntu Dell despite bluetooth off and touchpad off also
I have a jumping pointer issue, I've come across multiple solutions but none worked. I turned off bluetooth and wifi and touchppad, and the mouse kept clicking and moving randomly. Also, on screen keyboard randomly aoppears, although i have turned it off
I have ubuntu 20
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

dell inspiron
System Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: Precision 5560
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: 2D2BBK3
    UUID: 4c4c4544-0044-3210-8042-b2c04f424b33
    Wake-up Type: Other
    SKU Number: 0A62
    Family: Precision

Here is the output from xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2D24:00 04F3:2D24                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0945:00 04F3:311C Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0945:00 04F3:311C Touchpad             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Privacy Driver                       id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]


If you have Ubuntu 20 then you have a version of a Ubuntu Core product. If not please edit the question and put in the correct version info.
